# Seeding Carrierwave from external process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

In it's simplest form...

I'm using Carrierwave in an app to auto-upload images that exist on external sites so as to put as little load on them as possible. The first time I want to display an image I trigger Carrierwave to do the uploading.

The db is seeded with an image url written in a background Java process. Then in Ruby I assign the seed url to "remote_image_url" and save! to get the upload and versioning to happen. This all works fine.

However I have to store a field in the db that tells whether the upload has been triggered so that I don't trigger it every time the image is displayed. How can I tell if the "image" has been uploaded? The "image" field is actually an Uploader, is there a method that will tell me if it has been triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carrierwave downloads the remote file as soon as you assign it via `model.remote_image_url=`, and it moves the file to its final location (local storage, S3, etc) as soon as you call `model.save`. This happens synchronously, so if `model.save` has completed, and there hasn't been an error, your file has been stored.

To put it another way: If you just loaded a model from the database, and `model.image?` is true, then `model.image.url` should be a working URL.

Comment: The check `model.image?` works, I can have removed the flag from the db